# Convert an array of objects to the following structures

Tags: javascript

I have array with next structure

```
let arr = [
  { name: "1", value: "fsdfsdfsd" },
  { name: "text", value: "more fdsfsf" },
  { name: "number", value: 33 },
  { name: "formId", value: "5f3a3cb667f98b1cfa62d79e" }
]
```

And I need to get this one, but at the same time keeping the initial order

```
let arr = {
  1: "fsdfsdfsd",
  text: "morefdsfsf",
  number: 33,
  formId: "5f3a3cb667f98b1cfa62d79e"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could take the entries for a new object.

```js
let array = [{ name: "1", value: "fsdfsdfsd" }, { name: "text", value: "more fdsfsf" }, { name: "number", value: 33 }, { name: "formId", value: "5f3a3cb667f98b1cfa62d79e" }],
    object = Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ name, value }) => [name, value]));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: tell me what to do to keep the order the same, that is, the id was in 1st place after processing

Comment: that is the (new) standard, index like keys (positive 32 bit integers) are sorted by value at top, followed by other strings in insertation order and at the end, ther are symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [
 {name: "1", value: "fsdfsdfsd"},
 {name: "text", value: "more fdsfsf"},
 {name: "number", value: 33},
 {name: "formId", value: "5f3a3cb667f98b1cfa62d79e"}
];
let obj = {};
arr.forEach(e => {
     obj[e.name] = e.value;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
    { name: '1', value: 'fsdfsdfsd' },
    { name: 'text', value: 'more fdsfsf' },
    { name: 'number', value: 33 },
    { name: 'formId', value: '5f3a3cb667f98b1cfa62d79e' },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => ({ ...acc, [name]: value }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can the order be kept the same as before processing? it comes as part of the task